# Ignore params in urls

Tags: django

I need to bolt a quick city-specific thing onto a site I am currently building.  I am going to do it something like this - http://example.com/XX/normal-slug. What I have set up in my urls.py is this:

```
url(r'^(?P<city>[a-zA-Z]{2})/', include('homepage.urls', namespace='homepage')),
url(r'^(?P<city>[a-zA-Z]{2})/section/', include('section.urls', namespace='section')),

# etc
```

The problem I am encountering now is that all of a sudden my methods all are now expecting a "city=XX" param.  I plan to process the actual city business logic in a middleware.  My question is... is there anyway have django "ignore" the named param? I don't want to modify all my views now to take either **kwards or 'city' param.  If I hard code the city code, it does what I expect:

```
url(r'^XX/section/', include('section.urls', namespace='section')),
```

So can I replicate that behaviour, but dynamically?

(Also, I plan on something more robust further down the line, probably Django Sites)

Comment: have you tried `url(r'^XX/section/', include('section.urls', namespace='section'), kwargs={'city':'XX'}),`?

Comment: I think you misunderstood - I need to keep the regex, but pass no params

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the param as optional in the regexp with `?`:

```
url(r'^((?P<city>[a-zA-Z]{2})/)?section/', include('section.urls', namespace='section')),
```

If city is not sent in the URL, your view will receive `city=None`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a non-capturing regex to accept the parameter but not pass it to the views.

```
r'^[a-zA-Z]{2}/section'
```

Comment: Was a great solution, but the below answer also answered a question that I didn't yet know I needed - what if city part is not there (which sometimes it isn't)